# Flutter filtering Json data

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

I have a json data which i wan t to filter and get data that has specific value. first i got the json data and store it in a list.

```
List _amh = [];
  Future<void> readAmh() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/amh.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);

    setState(() {
      _amh = data["items"];
    });
  }
```

so the json data looks like

```
{
   "items": [
      {
         "chapter": 1,
         "verse": 1.
         "text": "Lorem Ipsum ....."
      },
      {
         "chapter": 1,
         "verse": 2.
         "text": "Lorem Ipsum ....."
      },
      {
         "chapter": 1,
         "verse": 3.
         "text": "Lorem Ipsum ....."
      },
      ....
      {
         "chapter": 2,
         "verse": 1.
         "text": "Lorem Ipsum ....."
      },
      {
         "chapter": 2,
         "verse": 2.
         "text": "Lorem Ipsum ....."
      },
      ...
      
   ]
}
```

so what i wanted is that when the user selects chapter one, i wanted to display the data related to that chapter. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use

```
List<dynamic> getChapterData(int chapter) {
  return _amh.where((item) => item["chapter"] == chapter).toList();
}
```

**Edit:**

Assuming the `_selectedChapter = 1` , you can use `ListView` to display the `text`

```
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: getChapterData(_selectedChapter).length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final verse = getChapterData(_selectedChapter)[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Verse ${verse["verse"]}'),
            subtitle: Text(verse["text"]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```